# Spring mvc, tomcat, displaying favicon issue

Tags: spring, jsp, tomcat, spring-mvc, favicon

Favicon is put into `webapp` folder.
Link in all jsp:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="${home}/favicon.ico" />
```

Resources mapping in servlet config context:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/favicon.ico" location="/" />
```

And mime description in `web.xml`:

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>ico</extension>
    <mime-type>image/x-icon</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

After that I can view favicon image via url `/favicon.ico`, but i still see default tomcat favicon on browser tab. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Check the network log of your browser (Firebug, Chrome dev tools, etc.). You'll see exactly what request the browser issued against the server to get the favicon. I suspect this

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="${home}/favicon.ico" />
```

does not yield the correct URL.

In order to ensure that any potential context path is added automatically I prefer to use this in combination with the [`c:url`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakh.html#bnakn) or the [`spring:url`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/UrlTag.html) JSP tags like so:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
...
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<c:url value='/favicon.ico'/>" />
```

Also, usually the `<mvc:resources>` piece and the MIME type declaration in `web.xml` are not needed. If you told us the final layout (i.e. folder structure) of the contents of your WAR file this question would be easier to answer.

Oh, and if the `favicon.ico` is in the root of your WAR file you don't even need the `<link>` tag as the browser by default looks for `http://server/favicon.ico`.

Did you check with more than one browser? Did you try to bookmark the page in browser (it should also load the favicon)?

Comment: Folder stucture of exploded war:
[link](http://clip2net.unet.by/clip/m604/1390335758-clip-7kb.png).
Chrome network log doesn't show any activity about favicon.

Comment: What is the URL to access the application? `http://server/eshop/` or is the context root only '/'? Also, you use JSPs with Spring WebMVC?

Comment: access url is "/". Yes, spring-mvc, jsp.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<base href="http://www.yoursitename.com/" />
```

(for all relative URLs on a page)

Comment: As this might have serious side effects on (other) relative links you need to be extra careful if you add it to an existing application. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base